# Invoke root shell from kernel

Tags: operating-system, linux-kernel, root

I am working on a exploit project which needs me to invoke a root shell from within the kernel. After searching through various documents and websites, I came to know that the only way to do that is to elevate the current process to root privileges and then execute instructions to invoke shell. This is because we cannot simply invoke a system call from kernel.

For the same, I have come across the call `commit_creds (prepare_kernel_cred (0));`, which can be used to grant root privilege to the process. However, I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4.4 Base and it does not have the above call:

```
[dmazumd@bn19-62 ~]$ grep commit_cred /proc/kallsyms 
[dmazumd@bn19-62 ~]$ grep _cred /proc/kallsyms 
c0164655 T compute_creds
c01a7cdd t dummy_bprm_apply_creds.....
```

So, my question is, how to go about this? 
I understand that the need is to set the `uid` of the process to zero which will provide it root privileges. AFAIK, the `uid` resides in `struct_cred` rather than `struct_task` now. And I am unaware if I can directly access these structures without the use of any API as mentioned above. Is there any other call to achieve the same? Or, is there any other approach?

PS: I am not asking for the exact answer to my question, any direction/help would be appreciated.

Comment: please care to comment why the question was down-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally achieve root shell by first elevating the process to root status while inside kernel. This was achieved by using the call `set_user(0)` call which is defined inside `/proc/kallsyms`.

Once this is done, the process switches back to user space using `iret` and then spawns a shell. This shell has root privileges.

Comment: Do you mean `setuid` instead of `set_user`?

Comment: nope, `setuid` is a system call, it is `set_user`. This may vary with the OS you use. While inside the kernel, we can only invoke routines defined in `/proc/kallsyms`. Also, the invocation is just a redirection to the routine address, not a function call as such.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd link to the definition of `set_user` in the source code. I didn't find it.

Comment: as i said earlier, these routines are OS kernel dependent, please check in your `/proc/kallsyms`

Answer (score 1):

To clarify things: Your kernel does not need 'root privileges'. It is actually above that. What you need is a process which can have privileges.

You could start looking what `execve` does to launch a process and do that.

If you've already a shell running AND you're in kernel mode, you could simply modify the `uid` in the `task_struct` ([shed.h](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/SO/LabLinux/PROCESY/ZRODLA/sched.h.html)).

Also, take a look [here](http://web.yl.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~tosh/kml/).

Comment: To start, that was an obvious typo which I am correcting (please look at my 2nd sentence in the question).                             Also, my question was not about how to spawn a shell, rather about setting the root privilege of the process. I am editing my question with more details.

Comment: I know nothing about you, so it's not obvious to me :) As for setting the privileges, you could do as I stated (task_struct modification) or look into the `execve` syscall and see how uids are set there.

Comment: I looked at ways to modify the `uid` before calling `execve`. It can be done with `setuid`. But, problem is that `/bin/bash` has protection around it. I tried linking `/bin/sh` to `/bin/zsh` instead, but doesn't help either, refer this document: http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs/Vulnerability/Buffer_Overflow/Buffer_Overflow.pdf

Comment: If I'm getting you right, you're attempting to elevate your privileges using a buffer overflow in an unprivileged program. This is not possible as such. You can only operate on the privileges the program has.

Comment: I read in the link above that it is possible once you link `/bin/sh` to `/bin/zsh/`. To elevate the privileges, I am using `setuid(0)`.

Comment: No. If the process you're exploiting has not the right privileges to set the uid, you can't use `setuid(0)`. It will just fail. If it would be possible to use `setuid(0)` only by linking some binary to another, there would be no need for IT security.